# Getting 'Unauthorized' error with xCMIS 1.2.2 WAR package over fresh Tomcat 7.0.28 install on Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, cmis

I have a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 box that I use for development.
I downloaded and uncompressed Tomcat 7.0.28 and put the xcmis.war that is in the xCMIS 1.2.2 distribution (the 'server' one, from the xCMIS Google Code page) in the webapps/ folder.
I started up Tomcat and pointed my browser to the xCMIS web app. I got the page of the xCMIS instance without any problem.
Then I started CMIS Workbench and pointed to the address labeled as REST Atom Services in the front page of my xCMIS instance (http://localhost:8080/xcmis/rest/cmisatom) Using the credentials provided (root / exo) I tried to connect. A small pop-up window appeared, saying 'runtime: Unauthorized'.
But when I tried the same using the Tomcat 6 bundle from the xCMIS page, it worked, i was able to connect, select a repository, and create folders and documents. But what I want is to take an ordinary Tomcat 7 and make it capable of serving a xCMIS repository without problems.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance,
- Sam

Update: I solved it by realizing that the reason for the Unauthorized error was an HTTP authorization error. Adding the same users that the example xCMIS Tomcat server had in its conf/tomcat-users.xml solved the problems.